# Blazor project template - some namespaces doesn't rename

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to make a Blazor  project template.
When i try to create a project from that template, all namespaces change properly to the project name, except for that in `_Imports.razor` and in the `@using` statement in the razor component. There are still the same namespaces as in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of my typical `_Imports.razor` files in a template

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using $ext_projectname$
@using $ext_projectname$.Core
```

and the relevant section in the vstemplate file:

```
    <TemplateContent>
        <Project TargetFileName="Blazr.Demo.UI.csproj" File="Blazr.Demo.UI.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      .......
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="_Imports.razor">_Imports.razor</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="program.cs">program.cs</ProjectItem>
        </Project>
    </TemplateContent>
```

If you want the context, you can see the whole template here:  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Template

Comment: I believe OP already had the project name template parameters set in their _Imports file and their razor component. I'm experiencing the same issue and have added the relevant vstemplate config with no luck.